# What is sigma in convolution kernel?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, gaussian, convolution

I've seen the notion of sigma many times, but never truly understand what it means and how it affects the kernel. Can anyone explain this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're referring to the kernel of a [*Gaussian filter*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter), which you create in MATLAB a function such as [`fspecial`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html) or its similar. If so, then `sigma` (σ) denotes the [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) of the filter's impulse response, which (in the one-dimensional case) is given by:

> `g(t) = 1/(sqrt(2π)σ)·exp-t2/(2σ2)`

The impulse response has the form of a [Gaussian bell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function). And how's the standard deviation related to all this? Well, according to the ["68–95–99.7 rule"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule), nearly all (~99.7%) of the values lie within 3 standard deviations of the mean, so this means that a Gaussian kernel needs at least 6σ-1 samples to function properly.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question right, sigma is the standard deviation of the Gaussian kernel. You can find detailed information on the [wiki page for Gaussian functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function). In short, higher the standard deviation, higher the blurring effect of the Gaussian kernel on an image, or indeed any 2D signal.